# Suggested replacement for setStartAtZero deprecated method not working

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have the following code for displaying a candlestick chart which works fine (the chart starts zoomed with the min / max Y values in frame):

```
    CandleDataSet dataset = new CandleDataSet(entries, "");

    dataset.setDecreasingColor(Color.RED);
    dataset.setIncreasingColor(Color.GREEN);
    dataset.setDecreasingPaintStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    CandleData data = new CandleData(labels, dataset);

    candleStickChart.getAxisLeft().setStartAtZero(false); //Deprecated
    candleStickChart.setData(data);

    candleStickChart.setDescription("Candlestick Chart");
    candleStickChart.animateY(1000);
```

However - according to [the docs](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-Axis)

```
setStartAtZero(boolean enabled): Deprecated - Use setAxisMinValue(...) or setAxisMaxValue(...) instead.
```

I have changed my code to the following but it doesn't seem to work (the chart starts with a Y value of 0 in frame which isn't useful when the minimum starts at say 13000):

```
    CandleDataSet dataset = new CandleDataSet(entries,"");

    dataset.setDecreasingColor(Color.RED);
    dataset.setIncreasingColor(Color.GREEN);
    dataset.setDecreasingPaintStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    CandleData data = new CandleData(labels, dataset);

    candleStickChart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMinValue(data.getYMin()); //New Code
    candleStickChart.invalidate();
    candleStickChart.setData(data);

    candleStickChart.setDescription("Candlestick Chart");
    candleStickChart.animateY(1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
candleStickChart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMinValue(data.getYMin());
```

Try:

```
candleStickChart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMinimum(dataSet.getYMin());
```

Comment: Do let me know if it works buddy and also text me anytime for further assistance. Happy coding :)